# Compile a package using JavaCompiler

Tags: java, compilation

Using a java program, I need to compile a package which has a group of `.java` files, post compilation i need to move `.class` files to a separate folder.

Instead of using `ProcessBuilder` class to execute the Java compilation from command line, I decided to use `JavaCompiler`. I am new to `JavaCompiler` and I succeeded in my first attempt of compiling one `.java` file at a time. But I don't know how to set classpath (`-classpath`),  destination folder (`-d`) and the list of .java files for package level compilation.

Can anyone brief me how to set the above said options?

Comment: you can also use [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/) to do this kinda task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Harry Joy, you may use ANT. What he probably meant is not using it from the command-line respectively with a build.xml file, but using it directly from your java program.
This way you will have access to the 'fileset/exclude/include...' functionality that you have in ant and save a lot of coding.

Example, pseudo code (not tested and probably not even compiling, just as hint):

```
Project p = new Project();
p.init();
p.addBuildListener( new SimpleBuildListener() );
p.setBaseDir( new File( "." ).getAbsoluteFile() );

Javac task = (Javac) p.createTask( "javac" );
task.srcdir( srcDirPath );

// Filsets can be built this way
FileSet set = new FileSet();
set.setDir( srcDirPath );
set.setIncludes( "**/*.java" );

task.addFileset( set );
```

Comment: Great, happy to hear that. :)